# Windows 10 Virtual Machines and DDA for GPUs

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, gpu, hyper-v

I have seen various articles that make reference to Windows 10 supporting DDA back to 2016, however I have yet to make this work (on Windows 10 Professional) following the steps in various Microsoft articles (including the one below).

"Hyper-V in Windows 10 Anniversary Update and in Windows Server 2016 has the ability to do Discrete Device Assignment, where a device like a GPU can be directly mapped into the address space of a guest VM."
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware-winpc/windows-10-for-workstations-and-dda/aebbfdb8-6c81-459b-8b64-0fed5f1fca90?auth=1

Then this article from 2017 says it's only for Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2016, Windows Server 2016.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/deploy/deploying-graphics-devices-using-dda

The article also says "This is preliminary content and subject to change."

Which is correct? Has anyone gotten DDA to work with GPUs? I have checked that my CPU, motherboard, etc all support use for DDA. Currently I am stuck when starting the VM. I get the error message:

"A hypervisor feature is not available to the user"

I have tried the solution [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/a7c2940a-af32-4dab-8b31-7a605e8cf075/a-hypervisor-feature-is-not-available-to-the-user?forum=WinServerPreview) but still no worky.

Comment: Based on the first link it would appear this is a Windows 10 Professional for Workstation only feature (other than Windows Server 2016) which you are NOT running.  Unless you are which you don’t make clear.  There is a good chance this is a Windows Server only Hyper-V feature based on the documentation dates (Professional for Workstation didn’t exist)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am running Win10 Pro (NOT Workstation) on the HyperV host. Might end up having to setup Workstation. Thanks again!

Comment: There is absolutely no guarantee it’s a feature of that edition, your link is inconclusive, but your current error message confirms Professional does not.

Comment: Do you want to post the answer you got from TechNet as the answer here?  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4069f3cf-559d-4f87-9247-25076535707f/windows-10-virtual-machines-and-dda-for-gpus?forum=win10itprovirt    I assume you're the same Maximojo

Comment: Good idea @essjae

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also asked on Microsoft Technet. See [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4069f3cf-559d-4f87-9247-25076535707f/windows-10-virtual-machines-and-dda-for-gpus?forum=win10itprovirt) but the crux of it is NO it is not supported on Windows 10:

"Hi,
After my massive search, from the latest official article [Plan for Deploying Devices using Discrete Device Assignment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/plan/plan-for-deploying-devices-using-discrete-device-assignment), we can see Discrete Device Assignment is applied to: Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2016, Windows Server 2016, Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2019, Windows Server 2019.

Supported Virtual Machines and Guest Operating Systems
Discrete Device Assignment is supported for Generation 1 or 2 VMs. Additionally, the guests supported include Windows 10, Windows Server 2019, Windows Server 2016, Windows Server 2012r2 with KB 3133690 applied, and various distributions of the Linux OS.

I am sorry, I still haven't searched about Microsoft's official website to explain that Discrete Device Assignment is available in Windows 10.

Best Regards,
Daisy Zhou"

Also [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/HyperV/comments/8jwt5c/windows_10_hyperv_dda/) has some additional user experiences in attempting DDA on Windows 10.